# Axios error : request failed with error code 500

Tags: next.js, axios

https://github.com/Elliott-Chong/chatpdf-yt/issues/43

This is the github link of the issue.

The error is as follows:

```
FileUpload.tsx:22 
 
 POST http://localhost:3000/api/createchat 500 (Internal Server Error)
mutationFn  @   FileUpload.tsx:22
Promise.then (async)        
onDrop  @   FileUpload.tsx:53
```

I have tried debugging and i guess that the error is in the code:

```js
mutationFn: async ({
      file_key,
      file_name,
    }: {
      file_key: string;
      file_name: string;
    }) => {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/createchat", {
        file_key,
        file_name,
      });
      return response.data;
      //console.log(response);
    },
  });
```

This is the route.ts file under /api/createchat

```
import { loadS3IntoPinecone } from "@/lib/pinecone";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"; 
export async function POST(req: Request) {
    try {

        const body = await req.json();
        const {file_key, file_name} = body;
        console.log(file_key,file_name);

        const pages = await loadS3IntoPinecone(file_key);
        return NextResponse.json({ pages });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return NextResponse.json(
            {error: "internal server error"},
            {status: 500}
            );
    }   
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

In the image attached, your request is hitting the api having path as `/api/create-chat`.
But the function you provided to handle those requests has endpoint as `/api/createchat`.

Make them same and it should work.

Comment: Yes i have tried changing it. actually i changed the file name from create-chat to createchat i did the same for the file name and the path but its still showing the error.